# (String)Iterator based conversion to int

Tags: c++, c++11

There are the `atox`, `strtox` and `stox` families that I know of, but I can't seem to find any iterator based string to int conversions in the Standard Library or Boost.

The reason I need them is because I am having a parser whose match result is a range referencing the input string. I might very well have an input string like

```
...8973893488349798923475...
     ^begin   ^end
```

so I need `738934883` as an integer.

Of couse, I could first take `begin` and `end` to construct an `std::string` to use with any of above families, but I would very much like to avoid that overhead.

So my question: Is there anything in the Standard Library or Boost accepting iterators as input, or do I have to write my own.

Comment: [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That would construct an `std::string`, and would thus be effectively no different than doing `std::string(begin,end)`, which invokes copies, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: No there's not such thing in STL, but sound good as proposal ;)

Comment: Try it out, *measure* and *benchmark* it, Don't just just dismiss the only solutions there really are because of some misconceptions about inefficiencies that might or might not exist. Don't fall into the pit of premature optimization, or dismiss solutions just because you don't like them. Try! Experiment! *Measure!*

Comment: I wonder whether .to.-functions are gonna be overloaded for `string_view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost does actually support this, using the [Lexical Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) library.  The following code uses a substring range to parse the number without performing any dynamic allocation:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int convert_strings_part(const std::string& s, std::size_t pos, std::size_t n)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s.data() + pos, n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string s = "8973893488349798923475";

    // Expect: 738934883

    std::cout << convert_strings_part(s, 2, 9) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output (tested on OS X with Boost 1.60):

```
738934883
```

The lexical cast library has some great features for conversion to and from strings, though it isn't as well known as some of the others for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Until gavinb's answer, I was not aware of any such library function. My try would have been this, using any of atox and strtox as follows (you could avoid a dependency on boost library then, if wanted):

```
::std::string::iterator b; // begin of section
::std::string::iterator e; // end of section, pointing at first char NOT to be evaluated
char tmp = *e;
*e = 0;
int n = atoi(&*b);
*e = tmp;
```

If you only had const_iterators available, you would have to apply a const_cast to *e before modifying.

Be aware that this solution is not thread safe, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with strstream but it was depracated. Below two examples, with strstream and boost arrays:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d4bde6973a1972

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>

 #include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
 #include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
 #include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "8973893488349798923475";
    //                  ^^^^^

    auto beg = in.begin()+2;
    auto end = in.begin()+6; 

    // strstream example - DEPRECATED
    std::istrstream os(&*beg, end-beg);
    int n;
    std::string ss;
    os >> n;
    std::cout << n << "\n";


    // Boost example
    namespace io = boost::iostreams;
    int n2;
    io::array_source src(&*beg, end-beg);
    io::stream<io::array_source> os2(src);

    os2 >> n2;
    std::cout << n2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern STL implementations `std::string(begin,end)` is not that bad - SSO eliminates any allocations for strings, smaller than ~15 chars (22 for 64bit).